# PHP MySQL WHERE SUM WHERE SUBSTRING

Tags: php, mysql, sum, substring, where-clause

I do not understand something! I want to create a query ... in the database under the following entry field stamp_updated, 2014-01-28 17:31:02.

Now I just want to have records with the tag 28:

`$ qry = "SELECT SUM (bytes) AS total FROM acct_v4 WHERE SUBSTRING (stamp_updated, 9,10) = '28 '";`

Unfortunately, I get no output, it's the SUBSTRING?

PS: 
What is supposed to be: I logged the port traffic, let him write in a database and would like to have daily statistics.

done ask new

Now I stand in front of logig proplem ... how do I put it best when I try to spend as Everyday Traffic?

> 2014-01-26: xx traffic  2014-01-27: xx traffic  2014-01-28: xx traffic

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
<?php 

function formatBytes($size, $precision = 2)
{
    $base = log($size) / log(1024);
    $suffixes = array('', 'k', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');   

    return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), $precision) . $suffixes[floor($base)];
}


$db=mysql_connect("localhost","traffic","....."); 
mysql_select_db("traffic",$db);
$qry = "SELECT SUM(bytes) AS total FROM acct_v4 
          WHERE SUBSTRING(stamp_updated,9,2) = '28' ";


$select = mysql_query($qry);
$result = mysql_fetch_array($select);


echo 'Summe: '.formatBytes($result['total']);  
//echo $result['total'];


?>
```

Comment: What's the column definition for `stamp_updated`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
SELECT SUM (bytes) AS total FROM acct_v4 WHERE DAY(stamp_updated) = 28;
```

Comment: this should work, assuming that the field is set to timestamp and not string.

Comment: Storing datetimes as strings is a bad plan because you lose a lot of this functionality. The `DAY()` function is exactly what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your SHOW CREATE TABLE, it looks as though you are after dates with 28 for the day. You should use MySQL's DAY function. This assumes that `stamp_updated` is a proper DATE or DATETIME field.

```
$qry = "SELECT SUM (bytes) AS total FROM acct_v4 WHERE DAY(stamp_updated) = 28";
```

Answer (score 0):

your `SUBSTRING (stamp_updated, 9,10)` will return 10 charcters after the position 9

--> `28 17:31:0`

this is the basic of `SUBSTRING`

```
 SUBSTRING(str, pos, len)
```

so in your case you should just change 10 to 2 like that

```
  SUBSTRING (stamp_updated, 9,2)
```

and it will work
your whole query will be

```
 $ qry = "SELECT SUM(bytes) AS total FROM acct_v4 
          WHERE SUBSTRING(stamp_updated,9,2) = '28' ";
```

Comment: Thanks now I have also understood SUBSTRING